# Why does my App is giving Error: DailyData is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

<kbd>Api->index.js</kbd>

```
import axios from 'axios';

const url = 'https://api.covid19india.org/data.json';

export const fetchDailyData = async () => {
    try {
      const response  = await axios.get(url);
      return response.data.statewise;
     } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
  };
```

<kbd>Body.js</kbd>

```
class Body extends Component {
  state = {
      dailyData: []
  };

    componentDidMount()
    {
        const fetchMyAPI = async () => {
        const initialDailyData = await fetchDailyData();
        // console.log(initialDailyData);  // giving correct data that is an Array 
        this.setState({
            dailyData: initialDailyData,
        })

        console.log(dailyData) // gives error : dailyData is not defined
        // console.log(this.dailyData) // gives undefined 
        };
        fetchMyAPI();
    }
```

My API is working well it is returning what I want but when I'm trying to set the `dailyData`
variable and after it when I'm trying to access it it is giving undefined or either giving error(when I'm using it without this..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dailyData` is a property of state object. so you should call from state

```
console.log(this.state.dailyData)
```

***you got empty array***

because react `setState` was async so you should call after the state update. its available on `setState` callback

```js
this.setState({
  dailyData: initialDailyData,
}, () => {
  console.log(this.state.dailyData) // you are received updated value
})
```

Answer (score 0):

State updates are async. You cannot immediately check it after updating the state.
There is a provision for callback in setState for **class components**

```
  this.setState({
            dailyData: initialDailyData,
        },()=>{ console.log(this.state.dailyData)
});
```

Edit: `dailyData` will not work, you will have to access it using `this.state.dailyData`